# Easting Northing data not consistent with UTM

Tags: r, coordinates, utm

I got a batch of UK coordinates with Easting-Northing readings. For instance, a coordinate of (321900, 536500) is shown to lie in the UK as expected ([gridreferencefinder](http://www.gridreferencefinder.com)). However, a standard UTM converter ([[rcn.montana.edu/resources/converter](http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/converter.aspx)) maps the coordinate to somewhere near Ivory Coast. As a beginner of geospatial data, my questions are:

1. What is the relationship/difference between X-Y coordinates in UTM and my Easting-Northing values (assumed to be UK Ordnance Survey coordinates)?
2. Can I perform distance calculations from Easting-Northing data the same way I do it for UTM?
3. If I need to convert my data to UTM first, how do I do that in R?

Comment: I thought so too... but when I convert the Easting-Northing values to lat-long in the first link, then convert the lat-long to UTM in the second link, it shows the zone to be 30, but does not give back the same value x-y values.

Comment: Yeah, I take back my first comment. Your Easting-Northing coordinates from the UK Ordinance Survey are not the standard Easting-Northing for UTM. Need to find the datum for this particular coordinate system (i.e., maybe UK specific).

Comment: This link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid may help

Comment: maybe better on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

1. See the link of @aichao in the comments
2. Yes
3. Do that after you assign the UK's CRS (t should be `CRS("+init=epsg:27700")` using the EPSG code.

   `library(sp)
    library(rgdal)
    uk <- data.frame(x=321900, y=536500)
    coordinates(uk) <- cbind(uk$x,uk$y)
    proj4string(uk) = CRS("+init=epsg:27700")`

Now your point is in the UK reference system.
When you know more about the UTM zone you want to use you can do:

```
CRS_new <- CRS("THE_RIGHT_UTM")
uk_UTM <- spTransform(uk, CRS.new)
```